# how to validate sqlite username & password with user input in xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have an sqlite database that is holding the usernames and passwords of every user that has signed up. I am now trying to create a login page but I don't know how to validate the user's input with that of the sqlite database.

My first idea was to convert the usernames and passwords stored on sqlite into a string arrays and then loop through those until it finds what the user has inputted in the login page, but none of the methods i've found online ended up working. Not sure if this is even the right approach.

This is the code in the DataBaseManager class which is supposed to select all the usernames:

```
public List<User> GetUNames(){

        return dbConnection.Query<User>("return dbConnection.Query<User>("Select * FROM [User] WHERE uName = @username AND Pw = @password");

    }
```

And this is where I've gotten to so far in the login page:

```
        DatabaseManager DBM = new DatabaseManager();

    private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DBM.GetUNames().Count; i++){


        }

        if (username.Text.ToLower()

    }
```

After the username validation starts working, then I'll just do the same for the passwords (the passwords stored on the app right now aren't hashed, I'll do that later on). Thanks!

**Based on Jason's answer, here is what I've changed:**

I've added this to the database Manager class:
`public bool ValidateUN(string username)
        {

```
        var results = dbConnection.Table<User>().Where(v => v.uName == username).ToList();

        return (results.Count() > 0);
    }

    public bool ValidatePW(string password)
    {

        var results = dbConnection.Table<User>().Where(v => v.Pw == password).ToList();

        return (results.Count() > 0);
    }
```

And this is what the login class looks like now:

```
DatabaseManager DBM = new DatabaseManager();



    private async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {

        if (DBM.ValidateUN() == username.Text.ToLower() && DBM.ValidatePW == password.Text()) {

            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Home());

        } else if (DBM.ValidateUN() != username.Text.ToLower()){

            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Username or password is incorrect", "OK");

        } else if (DBM.ValidatePW != password.Text()){

            await DisplayAlert("Error", "Username or password is incorrect", "OK");

        }


    }
```

But I'm getting errors in these areas in the login class:

`DBM.ValidateUN()` it says "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'username' of 'DatabaseManager.ValidateUN(string)'"

And also on `.Text` of `password.Text()`. it says "non-invocable member 'Entry.Text' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Authentication is a solved problem, you should not try to recreate that wheel. Look at Auth0 or Identity server. Note both of those (and every other one in existence) do not run on the client. If you put that database on everyone's phone it would take about 60 seconds to hack.

Comment: Hi, I've tried using auth0 and Identity server before, personally it was way too complicated. Also, this app is supposed to be for a school project and is only going to be demonstrated through the simulator on my mac, which is why I didn't continue with auth0 or Identity server. It's not going to be installed on any phone except on my own and a simulator. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: I see. Then maybe you simply want to do `Select * FROM [User] WHERE uName = @username AND password = @password`

Comment: I just changed it to what you suggested, but what should i do in the login page class?

Comment: Just check if you got a single `User` from the database.

Comment: Sorry but not quite sure how to do that

Comment: password.Text is a property, not a method, so it doesn't need "()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool ValidateUser(string user, string password)
{

    var results = dbConnection.Table<User>().Where(v => v.uName == user && v.Pw = password).ToList();

    return (results.Count() > 0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've updated my code but I'm still getting a couple of errors. I've updated my question to show what I have changed and what errors are appearing.

Comment: first, validating username and password separately will not work - it will return true if I enter User A's usernamee and User B's password.  Second, you need to pass the username/password as parameters to the function, and will return a bool (true/false).